# Custom keras layer isn't shown in model.summary

Tags: tensorflow, keras

When I try to look at the `.summary` of my model with my custom layers, I get the following outputs:

```
Model: "functional_29"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_118 (InputNode)           [(None, 1)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_119 (InputNode)           [(None, 1)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_strided_slice_156 ( [(1,)]               0           input_118[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_strided_slice_157 ( [(1,)]               0           input_119[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_120 (InputNode)           [(None, 1)]          0                                            
_________________________________________________________________________________________________   
tf_op_layer_concat_106 (TensorF [(2,)]               0           tf_op_layer_strided_slice_162[0][
                                                                 tf_op_layer_strided_slice_163[0][

...
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_strided_slice_164 ( [(1,)]               0           input_120[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_node_128_output (Te [()]                 0           tf_op_layer_Relu_55[0][0]        
==================================================================================================
Total params: 0
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Why is that? How can I wrap all of those operations under the label `MyLayer`?

Comment: Did you actually make a custom layer (subclass of Layer)? Without code there is not much to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own layer by subclassing from `tf.keras.layers.Layer`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input

class DirectLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    
  def __init__(self, name = "direct_layer", **kwargs):
    super(DirectLayer, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)

  def build(self, input_shape):
    self.w = self.add_weight(
            shape=input_shape[1:],
            initializer="random_normal",
            trainable=True,
        )
    self.b = self.add_weight(
        shape=input_shape[1:], initializer="random_normal", trainable=True
    )

    
  def call(self, inputs):
      return tf.multiply(inputs, self.w) + self.b

x_in = Input(shape=[10])
x = DirectLayer(name="my_layer")(x_in)
x_out = DirectLayer()(x)

model = Model(x_in, x_out)

x = tf.ones([16,10])
tf.print(model(x))

tf.print(model.summary())
```

I created a simple layer called DirectLayer. I built a model that uses that layer twice. The Input layer is there just to specify the shape of input data.

As you can see, you can easily specify the name of the layer.

The summary function produces the following:

```
Model: "functional_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 10)]              0         
_________________________________________________________________
my_layer (DirectLayer)       (None, 10)                20        
_________________________________________________________________
direct_layer (DirectLayer)   (None, 10)                20        
=================================================================
Total params: 40
Trainable params: 40
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```